# traversing, finding the max value and finding average of arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I was doing an assignment which was related to arrays. The question is:

"Complete the code segment to help Raj , find the highest mark and average mark secured by him in "s" number of subjects."

and here is the code segment which needs to be completed:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise1_5{
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     double mark_avg;
     int result;
     int i;
     int s;
  //define size of array
   s = input.nextInt();
 //The array is defined "arr" and inserted marks into it.
  int[] arr = new int[s];   
  for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
  {
arr[i]=input.nextInt();
    }
//hints given:
//Initialize maximum element as first element of the array.  
//Traverse array elements to get the current max.
//Store the highest mark in the variable result.
//Store average mark in avgMarks.


//my Attempt:
/*
for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) 
if (arr[i] > s){
s = arr[i];}
result = s;
System.out.println(result);


double sum= 0;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
  sum += arr[i];
double avgMarks=sum/i;
System.out.print(avgMarks);*/

}
}
```

Comment: this time i tried to be in community guidelines as much as possible...

Comment: What is the issue that your are facing?

Comment: The issue is that my code passes public test cases and one private case but fails in the second private case. Private test cases are cases in which the input and output is not told to you...

Comment: Why comparing `arr[i]` to `s`? `s` is the length of the array. You should set arr[0] to another variable say `max`, and compare `arr[1]`~`arr[s-1]` to `max`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there can be multiple ways to do. If arrays is the only data structure allowed and using the "hints given" to follow the existing code fragment, I think the algorithm can be:

1. Store the first element in variable result.
2. Then loop through the array and compare if the current element is larger than the variable result. If it is, then store it in variable result.
3. The highest value will be in variable result after the iteration.

   ```
    result = arr[0];
    mark_avg = 0;
    for (int e : arr) {
        if (e > result) {
            result = e;
        }
        mark_avg += e;
    }

    mark_avg = mark_avg / arr.length;

    System.out.println("Highest mark is " + result);
    System.out.println("Average mark is " + mark_avg);
   ```